# Win 10 app not running on minimizing

Tags: window, uwp, iot

I have made a IoT beacon reading app. I am using DispatchTimer to get signal for 10 sec then processing it to retrieve some result. Everything is working fine if app is not minimized. but when app is minimized or I work on some other thing then App is not working at all. I have handle App suspended event but still on minimizing the app I am not able show the result.

Comment: I think you may need to create a Background task to do this. See [Support your app with background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299103.aspx)

Comment: In Background task timer will not work at all, as background task will refresh in minutes not in second and I need to process the signal in every 10 seconds, for 3 times then again have to repeat this cycle.

Answer (score 2):

To keep your app running when minimized, you need to create an ExtendedExecutionSession in your app. Read more details here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590969.aspx

Thanks,

Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform